# (A ⊆ B ∪ C) → (A ⊆ B or A ⊆ C)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

(A ⊆ B ∪ C) ↔ (∀x)(x ∈ A → x ∈ B ∪ C)

(∀x)(x ∈ A → x ∈ B ∪ C) → (∀x)(x ∈ A → x ∈ B or x ∈ C)

(∀x)(x ∈ A → x ∈ B or x ∈ C) ↔ (∀x)(x ∈ A → x ∈ B or x ∈ A → x ∈ C)

(∀x)(x ∈ A → x ∈ B or x ∈ A → x ∈ C) → A ⊆ B or A ⊆ C

therefore, (A ⊆ B ∪ C) → (A ⊆ B or A ⊆ C)

but, if A = {x, y} and B = {x} and C = {y}, then B ∪ C = {x, y}, therefore A ⊆ B ∪ C, but, A ⊄ B and A ⊄ C, therefore (A ⊆ B ∪ C) → (A ⊆ B or A ⊆ C) is false.

Can someone explain to me what I did wrong?

Comment: Fourth line is wrong.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: What exactly is the error? I'm not convinced either, but by definition it would be equivalent, right?

Comment: P → Q v R = P → Q v P → R

Comment: I think the mistake is splitting up $/forall$x in 4rth line

Comment: In the 4th line the clause "$A ⊆ B$ or $A ⊆ C$" is NOT  implied by $∀x\,(x ∈ A → x ∈ B$  or $x ∈ A → x ∈ C) .$

Comment: Your fourth line is wrong. The mistake is thinking that $\forall$ distributes over $\lor$. In general it's false that $\forall x\,(A(x)\lor B(x)) \implies (\forall x\,A(x)\lor \forall x\,B(x))$/ For example, let $A(x)$ be "$x$ is even", and  $B(x)$ be "$x$ is odd".

Comment: I see, That's why that transition seemed so strange to me

Comment: but, in which cases "∀x" is distributive?

Answer (score 2):

Try running through your proof with $A=B \cup C$.  It's clear from this example that the implication need not hold, so running through your work with this example in mind will illustrate where you go wrong.

In this case, you'll see that your fourth line does not follow from your third line.  Specifically, it's not that case that

$$\forall x~((x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B) \lor (x \in A \Rightarrow x \in C)) \Rightarrow \forall x ~(x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B) \lor \forall x ~ ( x \in A \Rightarrow x \in C)$$

and it's the right-hand side of this implication that's equivalent to $A \subseteq B \lor A \subseteq C$.